# FPS視点を実装したい

Tags: c++, directx

初心者でも分かりやすいおすすめのサイトなどありますか？
DirectX11を使ったゲームフレームワークです。

Answer (score 1):

FPS視点の実装にはボーン入りでモーションが可能なキャラクターの描画まで出来ていることが最低ラインになります。そのキャラクターの目の位置にカメラをセットし、視点をキャラクターの向いている方向に合わせることで、FPS視点は完成しますが、ソースコードの記載もない現状ではこれ以上、答えようがありません。